# Why does Apple treat these apps specially?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, webkit

I just noticed this: http://opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-1298/platform/RuntimeApplicationChecksIPhone.h

It lists checks for various Apple and non-Apple apps:

```
bool applicationIsMobileMail();
bool applicationIsMobileSafari();
bool applicationIsDumpRenderTree();
bool applicationIsMobileStore();
bool applicationIsWebApp();
bool applicationIsOkCupid();
bool applicationIsSolarWalk();
bool applicationIsFacebook();
bool applicationIsFacebookTouchHD();
bool applicationIsEpicurious();
bool applicationIsDaijisenDictionary();
bool applicationIsNASAHD();
bool applicationIsMASH();
bool applicationIsTheEconomistOnIPhone();
```

Why are these apps treated differently by WebCore? When other apps are forbidden from interacting with WebCore without resorting to various hacks to avoid Apple's validation, why do they grant these apps special treatment?

All of these calls bar MASH, Epicurious and FacebookTouchHD are still present in the WebCore build in iOS 5.1.

Comment: Only Apple could really answer this question.  I doubt there's any "we did this because..." in the docs.

Comment: This question would better be asked on the Jail break development site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18154/ios-jailbreaking-development

Comment: I know that Solar Walk at least is commonly used in Apple stores as a demonstration app / demo version, so maybe Apple has done this to help apps like theirs.

Comment: A more answerable question would be: what capabilities does this check grant (or restrict) for those particular applications? Someone should be able to parse that out of the exposed WebCore code. In the process of finding that, it might shed more light on the "why?" question.

Comment: Upon digging into this a little further, and talking with one of the developers on this list, none of these applications received any special capabilities from Apple. This simply appears to be a check in WebKit for applications that expose a certain kind of bug, and this is a temporary workaround they put in place for this. They aren't receiving any special treatment.